# How to insert an SQL literal as a query parameter in Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

I want to insert part of SQL statement as a parameter instead of concatenation to have it neat:

```cs
connection.Query(@"
    SELECT @Fields
    FROM Table
    WHERE ID = @Id
    ", new { Fields = "A, B", Id = 1});
```

I tried wrapping the parameter string in a custom class and mapping the class using Dapper

```cs
public class SqlString
{
    public readonly string Value;

    public SqlString(string sql)
    {
        Value = sql;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

...

Dapper.SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(SqlString), System.Data.DbType.Object);
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize field names in T-SQL.

You will have to generate the dynamic SQL with your dynamic field names before you pass the sql string into the `Connection.Query()` method.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had to resort to my own SQL injector.